# What is the difference between $dx/x$ and $d(\log x)$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, differential-forms

I am not comfortable with differential forms and do not understand what $d (\log x)$ represents. My understanding is that since

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \log(x) = \frac{1}{x}
$$

then we can write

$$
d \log x = \frac{dx}{x}
$$

However, I have noticed that some authors make a distinction between these two quantities. For example, in [Hull's notes on variance swaps](http://www-2.rotman.utoronto.ca/%7Ehull/technicalnotes/TechnicalNote22.pdf), he writes

$$
\frac{\sigma^2}{2} dt = \frac{dS}{S} - d\log S
$$

It's not clear to me why the right-hand side is not zero. What is the difference between the two terms? Clearly, I am missing something about the notation around differential form.

Comment: Your first two expressions are correct. In particular when $log(x)$ is a function of $x$ only. The paper by Hull seems to address a more complicated situation, where a quantity $S$ depends on multiple parameters. Hence the differential form is less simple. You have to examine carefully all the assumptions made by Hull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an ordinary differential, the equality

$$\mathrm{d}(\log x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}$$

is true by the chain rule. (This formula holds even when $x$ depends on multiple parameters, as long as $x$ is continuously differentiable in any reasonable sense.)

However, for a diffusion process $S$, the differential $\mathrm{d}S$ behaves differently from ordinary ones, and is subject to the "stochastic version of chain rule" called **Itô's lemma** (a.k.a. Itô's lemma). In OP's case, this lemma tells that

$$\mathrm{d}(\log S) = \frac{\mathrm{d}S}{S} - \frac{\mathrm{d}[S]}{2S^2}, $$

where $[S]=([S]_t)_{t\geq0}$ stands for the [quadratic variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation) of $S$. The assumption in the note then tells that $\mathrm{d}[S] = S^2 \sigma^2 \, \mathrm{d}t$, hence

$$\mathrm{d}(\log S) = \frac{\mathrm{d}S}{S} - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \, \mathrm{d}t, $$

which is equivalent to what OP asked.

Comment: If one derives a (general) property In pure mathematics, it must be peculiar that in some sub-field of mathematics the property is no longer valid and must be replaced by something else. To me this sounds more like a model calculation. Make some assumptions, do the calculation and you arrive at a certain formula.

Comment: I also question the language regarding $S$. It is here called a diffusion process. And then $dS$ is the corresponding differential. But how can a differential be associated with a "process"? It makes more sense if $S$ is some state property, for example the total energy of a system. Then the differential has a certain physical meaning.

Comment: @M.Wind, There are a couple of things that makes differential of a diffusion process different from the ordinary ones. (1) A diffusion process (as a random function of time) has *extremely rough* paths, hence the usual calculus cannot be applied to them. This roughness is so high that the increment $\Delta S_t=S_{t+\Delta t}-S_t$, has typical magnitude of order $\sqrt{\Delta t}$, which is much larger than $\Delta t$ when $\Delta t$ is small.

Comment: This also tells that, in the Taylor expansion $$\Delta f(S_t) = f(S_{t+\Delta t})-f(S_t)=f'(S_t)\Delta S_t+\frac{1}{2!}f''(S_t)(\Delta S)^2 + \cdots, $$ the second-order term cannot be ignores because $(\Delta S)^2$ is typically of order $\Delta t$. That is essentially why Itô's lemma picks up an extra term compared to the usual change-of-variables formula. (2) When dealing with "stochastic differentials", one must take direction of time into consideration. So it naturally forces us to regard a diffusion process as a (random) function of time, $t \mapsto S_t$.

Comment: By the way, the term "process" in stochastic calculus literature simply refers to "random function in time", namely $$t \mapsto X_t$$ where each $X_t$ is random. I believe it is almost certainly different from what is called a process in physics.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.